# Bold and italics with taipy-gui

Tags: python, python-3.x, taipy

How to put a string in bold and italics on taipy-gui?

For example, I would like the word `famous` to have both styles.

```
from taipy import Gui

Gui(page="My *famous* app").run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Markdown syntax should work in Taipy. For example, you can use `***`:

```py
from taipy import Gui

Gui(page="My ***famous*** app").run()
```